# EhCache in Android for caching bitmap images?

Tags: android, caching, ehcache

I'm writing a fairly Android application which will need to cache a lot of different images around 48x48 to 500x500 pixels in size. These images are fetched over the network from a number of different sources (think: user selects a source, browses a bunch of images, changes source, browses a bunch of images, etc.). I'd like to implement caching for these images, as I don't want to hit HTTP if someone's flinging through some images they've already seen. Obviously, memory usage is pretty key, so that's where EhCache comes in, as it offers a lot of different options for bounding the cache, expanding it to disk, etc.

Is this the right/best way to go about caching these images? I have noticed a lot of applications cache right to disk on the SD card, but I'd like to avoid this if possible for the sake of speed/convenience.

Comment: Have you tried to cache the images on the disk before trying any in-memory cache? Remember that you only have very limited resource on your phone, and the system will kill your app when it need the resource back, but disk is always available there.

Comment: So I should write an entire caching system which will cache to disk? Is there a library out there which will simplify this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check out Matthias Kaeppler's project Droid-Fu:
https://github.com/mttkay/droid-fu

In Droid-Fu, there is an `ImageCache`, which uses memory for the first level cache, and disk for the second level. It it specifically made for Android, and does the right thing there, which is to use the designated cache directory for the current application instead of polluting the sdcard or other directories. Android can automatically clean up the cache directory when it needs to.

Here is the Javadoc:
http://mttkay.github.com/droid-fu/com/github/droidfu/imageloader/ImageCache.html

Comment: Android will NOT manage this directory, only when storage space is low (which is not the way you'd want a cache to work): "When the device is low on internal storage space, Android may delete these cache files to recover space. However, you should not rely on the system to clean up these files for you. You should always maintain the cache files yourself and stay within a reasonable limit of space consumed, such as 1MB. When the user uninstalls your application, these files are removed."

Comment: @MrSnowflake  Just because Droid-Fu uses the cache directory doesn't mean that it can't also clean up after itself.  Does it not?  I think Hugo's point was that it uses the appropriate location for storage, which is at least **eligible** to be cleaned up if Android deems it necessary.

Comment: @spaaarky21 I'm only saying the OS won't do it for you. If Droid-Fu does that, great! otherwise you should do it yourself!